# Blueman: RecentConns 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth, manjaro, bluez, blueman

The last update for manjaro, no longer allows me to enable blueman for some reason. Here is the error:

```
   Connection Failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dbus/service.py", line 707, in _message_cb
        retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/DbusService.py", line 36, in wrapper
        return method(*args[1:], **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/DBusService.py", line 76, in connect_service
        self.Applet.Plugins.RecentConns.notify(service)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/RecentConns.py", line 261, in notify
        for i in RecentConns.items:
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

`blueman-applet` gives

```
blueman-applet:1811): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2:19: Theming engine 'adwaita' not found
blueman-applet version 2.0 starting
Stale PID, overwriting
/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py:313: Warning: The property GSettings:schema is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
  return super_init_func(self, **new_kwargs)
_________
Load (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:60)
['NMDUNSupport', 'PowerManager', 'DhcpClient', 'AppIndicator', 'ExitItem', 'TransferService', 'GameControllerWakelock', 'Menu', 'PPPSupport', 'ShowConnected', 'Networking', 'StandardItems', 'AuthAgent', 'DBusService', 'SerialManager', 'KillSwitch', 'DiscvManager', 'NMPANSupport', 'StatusIcon', 'RecentConns', 'Headset', 'NetUsage'] 
_________
Load (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:60)
Unable to load plugin module AppIndicator
cannot import name AppIndicator3, introspection typelib not found 
_________
get_interface_version (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/bluez/BlueZInterface.py:13)
Detected BlueZ 5 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.Headset.Headset'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.TransferService.TransferService'> 
_________
get_interface_version (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/bluez/obex/Base.py:20)
Detected BlueZ integrated obexd 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.StatusIcon.StatusIcon'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.Menu.Menu'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.ExitItem.ExitItem'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.StandardItems.StandardItems'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.Networking.Networking'> 
_________
load_nap_settings (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/Networking.py:36)
Loading NAP settings 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.AuthAgent.AuthAgent'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
Not loading DhcpClient because it's conflict has higher priority 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.DiscvManager.DiscvManager'> 
_________
update_menuitems (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/DiscvManager.py:123)
warning: Adapter is None 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.RecentConns.RecentConns'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.PowerManager.PowerManager'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.ShowConnected.ShowConnected'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.GameControllerWakelock.GameControllerWakelock'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.DBusService.DBusService'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
Not loading PPPSupport because it's conflict has higher priority 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.NMDUNSupport.NMDUNSupport'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.SerialManager.SerialManager'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.NMPANSupport.NMPANSupport'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.KillSwitch.KillSwitch'> 
_________
io_event (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/KillSwitch.py:72)
killswitch registered 1 
_________
io_event (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/KillSwitch.py:72)
State: False 
_________
UpdatePowerState (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py:159)
off True 
foff False 
on True 
current state True 
new state False 
_________
UpdatePowerState (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py:159)
Signalling False 
_________
_on_obex_owner_changed (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/TransferService.py:170)
obex owner changed: :1.45 
_________
on_dbus_name_owner_change (/usr/bin/blueman-applet:94)
org.bluez owner changed to :1.2 
_________
set_nap (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/Networking.py:65)
set nap False 
_________
register_agent (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/AuthAgent.py:63)
Registering agent 
_________
enumerate_connections (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/ShowConnected.py:50)
Found 0 existing connections 
_________
on_registered (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/bluez/obex/AgentManager.py:18)
/org/blueman/obex_agent 
_________
RequestPowerState (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py:131)
Requesting True 
_________
on_power_state_change_requested (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/KillSwitch.py:119)
True 
_________
UpdatePowerState (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py:159)
off True 
foff False 
on False 
current state False 
new state False 
_________
check (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py:119)
callbacks done 
_________
set_adapter_state (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py:90)
True 
_________
set_adapter_state (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py:90)
Exception occurred org.bluez.Error.Blocked: Blocked through rfkill
```

gnome-themes-standard is installed.

They labeled my ticket as bug on github, i think I will never receive an answer and have to wait till the next release of blueman to get it fixed. I can't wait that long, is there another bluetooth applet available for xfce?

Comment: Did you report [this bug](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/327)?

Comment: @eyoung100 yes.

Comment: Did you update Python to 3.4 without rebuilding packages that depend upon it?

Comment: @eyoung100 I don't really know what was upgraded, I just ran `sudo pacman -Syuu` and pacman should usually take care of dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran

`sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`

and it seems to work, however on github, Christopher Schramm reopened my ticket and still labeled bug, maybe he is investigating a bug I don't know of, perhaps the GTK bug. For me, all I care about is that it's working.

**Edit**

Christopher found an actual bug, look at `blueman/plugins/mechanism/RfKill.py` and change your file according to this, or wait until the update is pushed. line 15 should look like

`f = open('/dev/rfkill', 'wb')` just add the b

Answer (score 2):

Small update for Lynob's answer: I have faced the same problem and found that `blueman-applet`, at least in v. 1.99, has the same bug but the problematic code is located in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/KillSwitchNG.py`. 
Lines 87-88:

> flags |= os.O_NONBLOCK 
>   self.fd = os.open("/dev/rfkill", flags) 
>   ...

To fix the problem `binary mode` bit must be also set in `flags` by adding this line before `open(...)` call:

> flags |= os.O_BINARY